# Taking $4$ letters at a time from the word EXAMINATION,how many permutations and combinations can be made?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Taking $4$ letters at a time from the word 'EXAMINATION', how many

(i) permutations

(ii) combinations

can be made?

Comment: Welcome to Math. SE. You can certainly ask questions here but it is expected that you also show your effort in solving them so that someone may help you. This site is not for posting homework problems without effort

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please include any work you have done to attempt to come up with an answer, so we know better how to help.

Notice, a permutation is an ordered set, thus order matters. How many ways are there to make a 5 permutation out of 11 elements? Think about that, and divide out your repeated letters: a is repeated twice, i is repeated twice, and n is repeated twice. Remember the formula for permutations: $n!/(n-r)!$ 5 is your r, 11 is your n.

In combinations, order doesn't matter, so there will normally be fewer numbers of combinations. This is your hint :)

Answer (score 0):

$(i)$ Total no. of permutations of the word $\bf{EXAMINATION}$

We have $11$ letters$(2A,2I,2N),E,X,M,O,T$

and we have to form $4$ letter word

So we will form Different cases.

$\bullet\; $ All $4$ letters are different: $\displaystyle \binom{8}{4}\times 4! = 1680$

$\bullet\; $ Here $2$ like and $2$ different :$\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}\times \binom{7}{2}\times \frac{4!}{2!}=756$

$\bullet\; $ Here $2$ alike and $2$ alike  :$\displaystyle \binom{3}{2}\times \times \frac{4!}{2!\times 2!}=18$

So Total no. of permutations of the word $\bf{EXAMINATION}$ is $$\displaystyle \left[\binom{8}{4}\times 4!\right]\times \left[\binom{3}{1}\times \binom{7}{2}\times \frac{4!}{2!}\right]\times \left[\binom{3}{2}\times \times \frac{4!}{2!\times 2!}\right]$$

So we get $\displaystyle =1680+756+18 = 2454$

$(i)$ Total no. of Combination of the word $\bf{EXAMINATION}$

We have $11$ letters$(2A,2I,2N),E,X,M,O,T$

and we have to form $4$ letter word

So we will form Different cases.

$\bullet\; $ All $4$ letters are different: $\displaystyle \binom{8}{4} = 70$

$\bullet\; $ Here $2$ like and $2$ different :$\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}\times \binom{7}{2}=63$

$\bullet\; $ Here $2$ alike and $2$ alike  :$\displaystyle \binom{3}{2} =3$

So Total no. of Combination of the word $\bf{EXAMINATION}$ is $$\displaystyle \left[\binom{8}{4}\right]\times \left[\binom{3}{1}\times \binom{7}{2}\right]\times \left[\binom{3}{2}\right]=70+63+3 = 136$$